# Math operations between values in list and list of lists (python3)

Tags: list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm stuck on what seems to be an easy problem :

I've got 2 lists of lists, let says :

```
a = [[1], [2]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And I want this result :

```
result = [[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

by adding (or, why not, substracting )  a[0] value to each value of b[0], then a[1] to b[1] etc...
I've tried using zip without result as expected:

```
result = [x for x in zip(a, b)]
```

Can someone help me to progress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a list of lists with 1 element, and you want to apply addition of that element on all elements of the other list. Since expected result is a list of lists, you have to create a double list comprehension, like this:

```
a = [[1], [2]]
b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

result = [[x+v for x in l] for [v],l in zip(a,b)]

print(result)
```

result:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

`for [v],l` is a neat way of unpacking the element inside the list so it avoids `x+v[0]` in the loop and it's more performant (and pythonic). Plus: if the list suddenly contains more than 1 element, you'll get an unpack error instead of an unexpected result (by ignoring further elements).

Comment: Yeah! Works for me, thanks :-) That's the way I was searching to make it. I've never made double list comprehension so far...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using numpy, which inherently supports array operations such as this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> i = np.array([[1], [2]])
>>> j = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> i+j
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

If your lists are large, this may have a speed advantage over list comprehensions due to the fact that numpy uses fast low-level routines for this sort of stuff.

If not, and you don't already have numpy installed, then the overhead of installing another library is probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I keep your solution in mind in case I'll use numpy later